# How to add virtual column made of two existing to symfony 2 class

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, knppaginator

I have a class User that is mapped to database table and has two variables/columns: name and surname:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max = 255)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max = 255)
 */
private $surname;
```

And I would like to add nameSurname that will be concat from two above.

I need that because of possibility to sort and search through whole name and I am using KNPPaginator bundle for creating sortable table on output. Result should be sortable and searchable column with both name and surname.

Solution should be preferably as annotation if possible.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Add your column:

> ```
> /**
>  * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
>  * @Assert\NotBlank()
>  * @Assert\Length(max = 255)
>  */
>
> private $nameSurname;
> ```

Add lifecycle callback:

> ```
> /**
>  * @ORM\PrePersist
>  */
> public function setNameSurname()
> {
>     $this->nameSurname = $this->name . $this->surname;
> }
> ```

Do not forget insert following line into class annotation:

```
@ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
```

All of this you can read in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#lifecycle-callbacks)

Comment: But that will create real column right? I want virtual one just for reading for KNPPaginator as I cant give it to him by manual doctrine call.

Comment: What do you mean saying "virtual column"? How it should be stored?

Comment: Well the nameSurname variable would be like CONCAT(name, ' ', surname). I dont want to have another real column just for this. The reason I want to have this is to be able to sort and search whole names in KNPPaginator table.